# Extend Woocommerce search by custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, custom-fields

From what I see, the Woocommerce search engine searches by the title and the content.

I would like to add a search by custom field value

I have read many posts with a similar problem. A lof of users recommend `pre_get_posts` or `woocommerce_product_query` for that.

I tried to do this with that method:

```
function custom_search( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        if ( $query->is_search() ) { 

            $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'       => 'product_code',
                'value'     => $query->query['s'],
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'  
            );

            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

        }

    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query' , 'custom_search' );
```

but it does not work like that

I would like to let my users to search products by name or code (code it's my custom field).

Comment: Please avoid asking the same question on Stack network as you have already asked [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338567/extend-woocommerce-search-by-custom-field-value) on Wordpress StackExchange.

Comment: Ok sorry for that. I didn't know about this rule. I will follow this principle

Comment: It's not a rule, It's just that you need to select where you are going to ask a question. So you can first ask on WPSE… then if nobody answers, you can delete it from there and ask it here (or the contrary)